# Is it possible to use conditional design:attribute tags?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-builder

I'm building a Lightning component for communities and haven't found any questions mentioning this requirement.

I've got `design:attribute` elements for component configuration, mainly, the rating type.

```
<design:attribute name="ratingType" label="label here" description='Description here' datasource='Type 1,Type 2,Type 3'/>
<design:attribute name="conditionalCheckBox" label="label here" description='Description here'/>

<aura:attribute name='ratingType' type='String'/>
<aura:attribute name='conditionalCheckBox' type='Boolean'/>
```

I have another design attribute that is only applicable if, for example, type 1 is selected in the component configuration. If type 1 is selected, I'd like to display a checkbox (`conditionalCheckBox`) for further customization. Is it possible to only show this checkbox design attribute in the component configuration based on a previous selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design file is static file with no JS controller attached to it .This sounds like a good candidate for an ideaExchange but currently do not think the platform provides you this ability .

Comment: I suspect you're right, I went ahead and created an idea for this. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4AFQA0

Comment: @AntonioManente Just upvoted it as well .